# Easily update table in Joomla 1.6

Tags: joomla-extensions, joomla1.6

Every day i need update several tables and add some new files to my website.
I think that edit Home article every day is an operational risk that i want to avoid.

I'm looking for a Admin Extension that could help me in this job. It would be nice if i could import an excel file (csv) to update my table.

I found some nice extensions (EasyTable Pro and Fabrik) but my Joomla version is 1.6 :/

Comment: First thing you need to do is update your site to Joomla 2.5. Your version is no longer supported. How big is the table you are editing? Is it 4 or 5 records with 3 or 4 columns or is it 300 records with 30 columns each? The size of what you are updating makes a difference in the way you would approach the set up.

Comment: The problem to update my Joomla! is the time that i spend trying to find extensions for the new version. If i could, i would still be using 1.5. I need to update 5 rows every day. I have a Excel macro that make my calculation and generate a table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't found a good extension, so i did a macro that generate HTML code.
Now i can run my macro, copy the HTML Code and paste it in a new article.

Answer (score 0):

Most extensions that are 1.6 ready will also work for 2.5 so you shouldn't have much of an issue updating.

In any case, what I would do since you are already doing the data entry every day is use a CCK to create the page. You should be able to create extra fields for each of your data points, then have the calculation done on site. This would free you from having to enter anything in to Excel first. Once you enter the data it would simply be a matter of formatting the output in to a table with the calculated numbers added in. It would be a little tricky, but I know for sure it could be done with K2 and extra fields, and I'm pretty sure it could be done with Zoo and Seblod.

You could also do it pretty easily with ChronoForms and ChonoConnect as well.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your reply. But i already need the excel file for other purposes. However, CCK decreases my operational risk.

Comment: Ok, too bad you can't replace the excel file, but having a CCK that allows you to create a new item/article each day makes it trivial to unpublish information should a problem arise, leaving you with the previous day's information while you fix the issue.